# How to add rows into data table using jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm trying to store data into database by ajax request and display stored data in datatable wihtout reloading the page. My form data is stored perfectly but table row does not add perfectly.

Here is my form

```
      <form id="videoAddForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="ms-form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="ms-form-group">
                            <label for="location">Video Url</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success mb-2">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is the ajax request

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#videoAddForm', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: config.routes.add,
            method: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {

                if (response.success == true) {
                    var videoTable = $('#videoTable').DataTable();
                    videoTable.row.add([
                        "" + response.data.name + "",
                        "" + response.data.location + "",
                        "<label class='ms-switch'><input type='checkbox'><span class='ms-switch-slider ms-switch-success round'></span></label>",
                        "<button type='button' class='ms-btn-icon btn-dark mr-3' onclick='editVideo(" +
                        response.data.id +
                        ")'> <i class='flaticon-pencil'></i></button> <button type='button' class='ms-btn-icon btn-danger'  onclick='deleteVideo(" +
                        response.data.id + ")'> <i  class='flaticon-trash'></i></button>",
                    ]).draw();
                    $('#videoTable tr:last').addClass('item' + response.data.id + '');
                    // $('#output_image').empty();
                    // $('#addSlider').modal('hide');
                    if (response.data.message) {
                        html =
                            '<div class="alert alert-success bg-success text-dark text-center" role="alert">' +
                            response.data.message + '</div>';
                        $('#videoAddForm').trigger('reset');

                    }
                    $('.showError').fadeIn(100).html(html);
                    $('.showError').fadeOut(3000);


                } else {
                    html =
                        '<div class="alert alert-danger bg-danger text-danger text-center" role="alert">' +
                        response.data.error + '</div>';
                    // $('#addSlider').modal('hide');
                    $('.showError').fadeIn(100).html(html);
                    $('.showError').fadeOut(3000);
                }
            }, //success end

            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#addVideo').modal('hide');
                $('.ajax_loader').show()
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.ajax_loader').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is my controller code

```
public function videoStore(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'location' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $data          = array();
        $data['error'] = $validator->errors()->all();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'data'    => $data,
        ]);
    } else {
        $videos = Video::create([
            'name'     => $request->name,
            'location' => $request->location,
        ]);
        $data             = array();
        $data['message']  = 'Video created successfully';
        $data['name']     = $videos->name;
        $data['location'] = $videos->location;
        $data['id']       = $videos->id;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In dataTable, row added but Sometimes row added at top, sometimes row added into middle & and sometimes added in the bottom. Also I want to add class into newly created tr. I tried this

```
   $('#videoTable tr:last').addClass('item' + response.data.id + '');
```

But it did now work.
Can anyone tell how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a row like normal, and after inserting row via ajax, just call

`$('#videoTable').DataTable();`

It is to reinitialise the datatable